# I want to hide an element permanently (Or Certain period) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a DIV permanently when use click on **Hide**
I have tried using jquery **hide()** but it appears automatically when they reload the web browser.

## Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".word-meaning-footer").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent(".word-meaning-item").hide();
    });
});
```

**Here is my HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="word-meaning-item">
     <h2 class="meaning-title"> <span> 101. </span> Always </h2>
     <p class="word-meaning-footer"> Hide </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to write the state somewhere like local storage. On document ready, load all states and hide the appropriate items. On click, write the state for that item.

Comment: You're doing it right way. So you're missing an item which is storing the user input, so you can retrieve the user input when the page reloads again and based on that you need to hide again. You can try doing it by `localstorage`.

Comment: Well, sure: that's how web pages work. The browser gets the HTML source and builds a page instance off of that, including running any JS. So: someone who loads this page will get a div with an h2 and a p, and when they click "hide", things get hidden _for that page instance_. If a user reloads, that loads _a new page instance_ from the same source code. If you want things to persist across page instances, you're going to have to put in a lot more code, involving localStorage or sessionStorage, so you can store and retrieve data associated to a specific page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage`:

```js
var ishidden = localStorage.getItem("ishidden") ? localStorage.getItem("ishidden") : 0;

if(parseInt(ishidden)){
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".word-meaning-footer").parent(".word-meaning-item").hide();
});
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".word-meaning-footer").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent(".word-meaning-item").hide();
        localStorage.setItem("ishidden",1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have many elements with **.word-meaning-item** When I click on Hide it hidden all elements. Please check the link: http://commonvocabulary.xyz/app/hundred-one.html

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `localStorage`. Note: example does not work because frame is sandboxed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".word-meaning-footer").click(function() {
    jQuery(".word-meaning-item").hide();
    window.localStorage.setItem('hidewordmeaningitem', true);
  });
  jQuery(".word-meaning-footer2").click(function() {
    jQuery(".word-meaning-item").show();
    window.localStorage.setItem('hidewordmeaningitem', false);
  });
  var hidewordmeaningitem = window.localStorage.getItem('hidewordmeaningitem');
  if(hidewordmeaningitem=="true")
  {
   jQuery(".word-meaning-item").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word-meaning-item">
  <h2 class="meaning-title"> <span> 101. </span> Always </h2>
  <p class="word-meaning-footer"> Hide </p>
</div>
<p class="word-meaning-footer2"> Show </p>
```